Change x-label after chart has already been created
Say I have:
import altair as alt
import polars as pl

chart = (
    alt.Chart(pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}))
    .mark_point()
    .encode(x="a", y="b")
)

Suppose I have a function which receives this chart object, and within that function, I'd like to change the x=axis to be 'a (£)'. How can I do that?
I can change the title with chart.properties(title='my title') but can't find a way to change the x-axis label text

One way I've found to do this is
chart.encoding.x.title = 'a (£)'

but this is "in-place" - is there a way to do it such that it won't modify the original chart?

You could use chart.configure_axisX(title='a (£)'), see this section in the docs.

thanks @joelostblom - I've tried that, but then the x-axis label disappears completely from the chart. might this be a bug?

Yup, follow up here https://github.com/vega/altair/issues/3582

you can simply create a new chart with the updated label using encode. Here's how:
import altair as alt
import polars as pl

chart = (
    alt.Chart(pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}))
    .mark_point()
    .encode(x="a", y="b")
)

def update_x_label(original_chart, new_label):
    return original_chart.encode(
        x=alt.X(original_chart.encoding.x.shorthand, title=new_label)
    )

new_chart = update_x_label(chart, 'a (£)')
new_chart.show()

Instead of directly modifying chart.encoding.x.title, which would change the original chart in-place, this approach creates a new chart by updating the x encoding with a new title. The original chart remains unchanged, and now you have a fresh chart with the new x-axis label.
